# Bootstrap 3 large button breaks out of Jumbotron on mobile screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my layout, I have a Jumbotron with a large button as the call to action

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Let's Buy Something Fancy</a>
```

However, on the XS mobile view, the button breaks out of the Jumbotron, see screenshot below:

http://screencast.com/t/d3VJRps0Rx7

I tried adding a row & new column, then changing to a 'btn-block' - and while the button stays in the Jumbotron, the text still bleeds out.

Is there a way to just get the button to size down on a small mobile screen?  Maybe from a large to a normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use media queries to scale the button down on smaller devices..

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .btn-responsive {
    padding:2px 4px;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height: 1;
    border-radius:3px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  .btn-responsive {
    padding:4px 9px;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/109303

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be the length and size of the text that forces the button to bleed out.
One solution could be to change the font-size with media query at the same breakpoint as bootstraps.